# Consultar o registro mais duplicado

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com um problema para recuperar o professor que leciona mais disciplinas nesta tabela, nesse caso eu quero recuperar o codigo que mais tem registros duplidos na coluna cod_prof.

```
create table aluno_professor_disciplina (
    matricula int,
    cod_prof int,
    cod_disc int,
    primary key (matricula, cod_prof, cod_disc),
    foreign key (matricula) references aluno(matricula),
    foreign key (cod_prof) references professor(cod_prof),
    foreign key (cod_disc) references disciplina(cod_disc));

INSERT INTO aluno_professor_disciplina VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO aluno_professor_disciplina VALUES (1,5,2);
INSERT INTO aluno_professor_disciplina VALUES (2,2,3);
INSERT INTO aluno_professor_disciplina VALUES (3,3,5);
INSERT INTO aluno_professor_disciplina VALUES (3,4,5);
INSERT INTO aluno_professor_disciplina VALUES (1,5,5);
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Estou tentado isso, mas não esta dando certo:

```
select A.nome, count(B.cod_prof) as QT_DISC from professor as A 
inner join aluno_professor_disciplina as B 
    on A.cod_prof = B.cod_prof
group by (A.nome);
```

Ele retorna o nome dos professores e a quantidade de disciplinas que cada um leciona, queria saber como eu posso recuperar somente o que leciona mais disciplinas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua consulta já retorna os dados corretos da quantidade que ele leciona você pode ordenar por QT_DISC decrescente (do maior para o menor) e então selecionar (limitar) apenas 1 registro.

```sql
select A.nome, count(B.cod_prof) as QT_DISC
from professor as A 
inner join aluno_professor_disciplina as B 
    on A.cod_prof = B.cod_prof
group by A.nome
order by QT_DISC DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Legal, entendi a lógica e deu certo aqui, no seu codigo, faltou apenas colocar o 'DESC' no order by. Valeu!!

Comment: Ops, my bad. Vou corrigir.